# Is there a public repo where I can contribute to the MySQL .NET connector?

Tags: mysql, c#, ado.net

We have found ourselves making some performance and scale improvements for the MySQL .NET driver from here http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

We know where to get the source in a ZIP archive. But is there a proper source repo that we can contribute to? A google search yields a blank.

Comment: Check this page: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Contributing+Code+to+MySQL

Comment: You can also ask the MariaDB (the other active MySQL fork) [developers](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/community-contributing-to-the-mariadb-project/) whether it's worth to submit the improvements in their codebase as well. I suppose if the code is approved my the Oracle MySQL team, it will eventually find its way into that codebase as well but I have no idea about the various licence related issues.

Comment: @Mat: That seems like a terribly long winded and corporate way to do OSS development. And no public GIT/Mercurial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing, there is not public repository for Connector/NET, if you have performance/scaling improvements you are welcome to contribute them (together with a bug report) at bugs.mysql.com.